# Fetch Span Value on specific Website

Tags: javascript, java, html

So i have a java code to fetch the values from a span. But the values comes null. now i am not sure what might be the issue. If the span is written in javascript, is it possible to extract those values from the span using Java on eclipse?

Here is my code and i am using JSoup:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{

    Document document = Jsoup.connect("https://www.binary.com/trading?l=EN").userAgent("Mozilla").get();
    Elements elements = document.select("span#spot");
    for (Element element : elements) {
      System.out.println(element.text());
    }


}
```

}

As mentioned earlier, i get no values on console. But if i try this on other websites, i get the data with no issues. Is there anyway to fetch these values?

Comment: You either need to have a static span in the html response from the server or parse JS. if you don't have control over the website then you're stuck with the latter solution - assuming the span isn't already a part of the response - which is a headache and probably not worth it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is if the span is added using javascript, it's not present as part of the response your code gets.

You need to ensure that your code can run JS just like browser would to obtain the result and trigger all the actions that lead to obtaining this result if any.

I would recommend against doing this, and reside to obtaining proper API source for this.